# Rpostgresql: Properly escaping strings for input

Tags: sql, r, rpostgresql

I am bridging R and psql, wish to remove vulnerability to sql injection.  Looking at documentation, I had hoped that:

```
postgresqlExecStatement(con, statement, params, ...)
```

Would allow use of something like:

```
postgresqlExecStatement(con, "DELETE FROM foos WHERE id = ? AND baz = ?", c(1, "bar"))
```

But unfortunately this does not seem to work.  Maybe I'm using the wrong 
symbol for parameter (something other than ?).

Best compromise I've found is escaping strings via:

```
postgresqlEscapeStrings(con, string)
```

(note: connection is necessary so function can know how to properly escape).

Means I have to escape every string I use in a paste when putting together 
my queries.  Not so elegant.  But seems best option.  Anyone have other 
ideas?

Comment: You might want to try https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres - it has full support for parameterised queries and implements the dbi generic `dbQuoteString()` and `dbQuoteIdentifier()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
postgresqlExecStatement(con, "DELETE FROM foos WHERE id = $1 AND baz = $2", list(1, "bar"))
```

I always pass my parameters to be bound as a list since `c` will force it into one mode. You also have to clear the results belonging to `con` if this statement succeeds before you can use it again.

Also, please note hadley's comments to use the new package `RPostgres`.

Comment: I don't think that will work because parameterised queries can usually only insert values, not parameters (i.e. the table name)

Comment: You are correct. I was answering from the perspective that one should use `$n` where `n` is an integer to construct a parametrised query with `postgresqlExecStatement`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments.  Your answer was great.  I've edited my question to remove the somewhat unreasonable request that the passed table name be escaped.